# Compactness and open sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

I have this small question, if $(E,\tau)$ is a Hausdorff space and $A,B$ two separated compact sets, how to prove the existence of two open disjoint sets $U$ and $V$ such that $B\subset V$ and $A\subset U$ ?

Please

Thank you.

Comment: By separated, do you mean disjoint? Also, what have you tried? Is this homework, or part of a homework question?

Comment: It's not a homework, i see it in a book and it says it easy to see that... , when $A,B$ are compact then from any open covering we can find a finite sub cover, but i don't understand why we must find two open disjoint sets $U$ and $V$

Comment: @PedroM. Separated is a slightly stronger term meaning $\overline{A} \cap B = \overline{B} \cap A = \emptyset$.

Comment: Since these sets are compact, disjoint is as strong as separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each pair of points $p\in A$ and $q\in B$, since the space is Hausdorff, there are open sets $U_{pq}$ and $V_{pq}$ such that $p\in U_{pq}$ and $q\in V_{pq}$ and the intersection of $U_{pq}$ and $V_{pq}$ is empty.

Fix $p\in A$, then consider $V_{pq}$ as $q$ varies over the elements of $B$.  This forms an open cover of $B$ so as $B$ is compact, there is a finite subcover.  Let $V_p$ be the union of the sets $V_{pq}$ in this subcover.  Now, let $U_p$ be the intersection of the $U_{pq}$ for the $q$'s that appear in this subcover.  Then you have open sets $U_p$ and $V_p$ such that $V_p$ contains $B$ and $U_p$ contains $p$ and $V_p$ and $U_p$ are disjoint.

Now, use a similar argument to complete the proof.

Comment: i don't understand what i must complete ?

Comment: This is only half of the construction.  I'm leaving the second half to you (you only have a pair os sets that contain $p$ and contain $B$), so try to take the argument I wrote above and reverse it to get $U$ and $V$.

Comment: i don't understand your proof at all

Comment: I am only using the definitions of compact and Hausdorff, so if it's confusing, I suggest reviewing those definitions.

Comment: i know this definitions but i don't understand why $U_{pq}$ why not directly $U$

Comment: I'm constructing $U$ and this is about half-way to the construction of $U$ (you can't start with $U$, you have to build up to it).

Comment: here you separate a point with a compact the second step is to separate the compact with a compact

Comment: right ??????????

Comment: @Vrouvrou Patience, please.  Yes, the first step is to separate single points from the compact set.  The second step is to reverse the process and separate the two compact sets.